# Install SOLR in a shared host

Tags: solr

Does anyone have any experience installing SOLR 4 in a shared hosting like rackspacecloud or godaddy?

Actually, is it possible?

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with shared hosts, but I can tell you what you would need: you need a webcontainer (jetty, tomcat) and your Solr instance needs rw permissions, to store documents and index files. Any service that gives you this (and that lets you install your software) is good to go.

Comment: My shared SOLR runs apache, but not sure about jetty/tomcat. I will try and give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I just got confirmation that it is NOT possible to install it. I would need a dedicated server.

Comment: Confirmation from where? And on what basis?

Comment: I got SOLR running on a shared host and a dedicated host.

Comment: I got confirmation from Rackspace but apparently they are wrong. O. Klein: how did you do it? If you can share some details then I could give it a shot too!

Answer (score 0):

You can run Solr on a VDS. However Java has some issues with OpenVZ on Ubuntu 12.04. It runs fine on Ubuntu 10.04 though.